# setting up a demo page on github

Tags: javascript, jquery, github

Is there a way to set up a demo page on a github project?

I see people having demo pages on google code, is there any way to also do that on github?

I only need it to do `html` `css` and `js` nothing server sided.

I'm trying to set up a multi-page ajax plugin so jsfiddle won't really help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to look at [github pages](http://pages.github.com/) using custom domains: http://help.github.com/pages/

> **Custom Domains**
>
> Let’s say you own the domain name example.com. Furthermore, your GitHub username is “charlie” and you have published a User Page at http://charlie.github.com/. Now you’d like to load up http://example.com/ in your browser and have it show the content from http://charlie.github.com/

Comment: +1 I'd missed you could use custom HTML for pages, I'd thought it was markdown only

Answer (score 7):

If your username in github is john, then you need to create a  new repository named `john.github.com`. you can do it in the way you created other repositories. Then commit files to that repository. If you put a `index.html` file in that repository, when people go to `http://john.github.com` they are supposed to see that `index.html` file.

So what you need to do is, create a repository named `<your_username>.github.com` and put your demo files there.

Comment: That's user's page (and should name the repo `john.github.io` nowdays); there are also per-project pages using `gh-pages` branch in existing repo: https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages

Answer (score 1):

Login to your GitHub and create a new repository named username.github.io, where username is your username (or organization name) on GitHub.
create your page(create you html css files ) and push the file to github this will create a page for you
I fount a good example here http://wiki.workassis.com/how-to-create-github-page/

ref : https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score -1):

You can add “http://htmlpreview.github.io/?”  before your "https://github.com/yourname/xxx.html".
You can check the setting options to comfirm your pages have pushed.